# Cordova batterystatus - how to get level straight away?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cordova, batterylevel

I am using this event:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#batterystatus

It works fine, it gets the batterylevel when it changes or when you start/end charging.

But how do you get the batterylevel straight away, when opening the app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You may write one plugin to get current battery level ,more about plugin dev check [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) and call this plugin inside **deviceready** event

****javascript***

```
 cordova.exec(function(status) {

       console.log(status); //will get current ststus

   }, function(error) {}, "Status",
                 "Status", ["givestatus"]);
```

this is the Native code  **Objective C**

```
- (void)Status:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
NSString* myarg = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

if (myarg != nil) {

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
double batLeft = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel] * 100;




pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"%.f",batLeft]];
} else {
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR    messageAsString:@"Arg was null"];
}

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

add new item to config.xml also

```
<feature name="Status">
    <param name="ios-package" value="Status" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :)

Can you please help a bit more, where to add these things? I am looking here, but I'm not 100% sure what to do.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html

I need to add a folder in /platforms/ios/appname/Plugins, right? And then I need to add status.h and status.m in this folder? But I'm not sure what to put in which files.

Comment: I included a .js file with this:

`CDV = ( typeof CDV == 'undefined' ? {} : CDV );
var cordova = window.cordova || window.Cordova;

cordova.exec(function(status) {

       console.log(status); //will get current ststus

   }, function(error) {}, "Status",
                 "Status", ["givestatus"]); `

And I added the feature reference in the config file. But I'm not sure how to implement the native code.

Comment: Changed one of the lines to this, now it works. thanks!

`pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", batLeft]];`